# Openbox environment for Windows

Tags: windows-8, openbox

I often find myself wanting to NOT multitask on Windows - or just have the machine devote as much as possible to a couple important programs, like photoshop. I really enjoy using openbox under Lubuntu, and have found that I can get good performance out of old machines.

I know how to disable startup programs and minimize the number of programs (and processes) running, but I was wondering if there were a way to make windows open only what I need for a couple of programs. I want to get back to my regular PC for general use, but it'd be great to have a "photoshop OS" or just a browser for when I need to look up something fast.

I'm not necessarily looking for a specific program, I'm looking for a way to devote as much processing power as possible to a couple of programs in a no-distractions environment, and preferably manage these environments and choose which I'd like at startup.

I'm running Windows 8 (and 10), HP Pavilion G6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [LiteStep](http://www.litestep.net/) or [BlackBox](http://bb4win.sourceforge.net/).
They are both very lightweight "windows shell" replacements, aka "windows managers".

Comment: Those look promising - I'll give them a try. Thanks!